# Find Neo4j nodes where the property is not set

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Using Cypher, how can I find a node where a property doesn't exist?

For example, I have two nodes:

```
A = {foo: true, name: 'A'},  B = { name: 'B'}
```

Now I'd like to find B, selecting it on the basis of not having the `foo` property set. How can I do this?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

As Michael Hunger mentioned

```
MATCH (n) WHERE NOT EXISTS(n.foo) RETURN n
```

On older versions of Neo4j you can use HAS:

```
# Causes error with later versions of Neo4j
MATCH (n) WHERE NOT HAS(n.foo) RETURN n
```

Comment: use `NOT exists(n.foo)` for future compatibility.

Comment: `Has` is no longer supported by Neo4j and produces an error

Comment: You can also use IS NULL and IS NOT NULL. For example

MATCH (n) WHERE n.foo IS NULL RETURN n

Answer (score 9):

As of [version 4.3](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/deprecations-additions-removals-compatibility/#_deprecated_features_2) `EXISTS` has been deprecated on properties and instead, you should use `IS NOT NULL`.

So for the example in your question your query would now be:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE n.foo IS NULL RETURN n
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MATCH (f) WHERE f.foo IS NULL RETURN f
```