# neo4j query to match nodes based on the number of properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a node with 8 properties and another node with only property under a common label. How can i match / query / display the nodes which has only property.

In other words, how can i match nodes which doesn't have more than 1 property.

Answer (score 1):

You may want something like:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE size(keys(n)) = 1
RETURN n
```

However note that this is a graph-wide query, and likely to be expensive. Confining the query to a label may help a little.

Comment: I guess this would take a long time as it has to calculate all the keys(columns) for every node.  Should work well if the data is small.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael Hunger mentioned

```
MATCH (n) WHERE NOT EXISTS(n.foo) RETURN n
```

Duplicate of the question : [Find neo4j nodes where property is not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35400674/find-neo4j-nodes-where-property-is-not-set)